# Custom data binding on ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I am trying to fill a ComboBox with multiple instances of a custom ComboBoxItem class. The ComboBoxItem class looks like this:

```
 class ComboBoxItem
 {
     public string Text { get; set; }
     public object Value { get; set; }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return Text;
     }
 }
```

I can fill the `CombBox` and read it's values just fine. My only problem is when an existing item comes in, the values should be bound to my `ComboBox`. But I don't know how to tell the `Binding` that it should use `ComboBoxItem.Value` as Value field.

```
//what to put in place of "SelectedItem"??
comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", row, "F_KundenId", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

Comment: comboBox.ValueMember = "Value";

Comment: I get an error "Cannot bind to the property on the target control" when I set the ValueMember to Value. I can do SelectedValue, but then I get 'null' (obviously).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I bind all my Windows ComboBoxes in my app:

First use this to load your dataSource, in this case a List:

```
    public static void LoadComboBox(ComboBox comboBox, object dataSource, string valueMember, string displayMember)
    {
        comboBox.DataSource = dataSource;

        comboBox.ValueMember = valueMember;
        comboBox.DisplayMember = displayMember;
    }
```

Then use this to bind the selected value to your "row" column "F_KundenId":

```
    public static void BindComboBox(ComboBox comboBox, object boundDataSource, string boundDataMember)
    {
        comboBox.DataBindings.Clear();
        comboBox.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", boundDataSource, boundDataMember);
    }
```

And here is a helper method to do both in a single call:

```
public static void LoadAndBindComboBox(ComboBox comboBox, object dataSource, string valueMember, string displayMember,
    object boundDataSource, string boundDataMember)
{
    LoadComboBox(comboBox, dataSource, valueMember, displayMember);
    BindComboBox(comboBox, boundDataSource, boundDataMember);
}
```

This code can be used with ANY datasources you want, and can bind to any column of a DataTable, DataRow or object.

Example:

```
LoadAndBindComboBox(comboBox, myItems, "Value", "Text", row, "F_KundenId");
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, alternatively to Mangist's answer, I have come up with a solution of my own. No need for any custom class. Just use `Dictionary<Key, Value>`. The only thing is that you have to be careful WHEN during runtime you set `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. If you reset the `DataSource` of the `ComboBox` (set it to null and rebind it), then you need to also set the two Member properties. Then just bind the `Dictionary<Key, Value>` to the `ComboBox` using a `BindingSource` object.

```
private void InitCombos()
{
    Dictionary<string, int> items = GetItems();    
    combo.DisplayMember = "Key";
    combo.ValueMember = "Value";
    combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
}

//This was where my problem was. I didn't set the two Member properties of my ComboBox, 
//thus preventing correct rebinding of DataSource
public void combo2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    combo.DataSource = null;
    Dictionary<string, int> newItems = GetItems();    
    combo.DisplayMember = "Key";
    combo.ValueMember = "Value";
    combo.DataSource = new BindingSource(items, null);
}
```